# how do you maximize the usability of a self-defined function in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am learning cakePHP 1.26.
A question came across my mind when I was creating a function in a Controller.
How do I maximize the usability of a self-defined function in CakePHP.

Here is my sample code:

```
function hello($id=null){

       $IfLoggedIn=$this->Session->check('user');

       if($IfLoggedIn){
        //search the database
        //$result=doing something from the search results
        $this->set('userInfo',$result);
        return "2";

       else if(!$IfLoggedIn && $id!=null){
       return "1";
        }

       else if($sid==null){
       return "0";
        }
}
```

and then in a .ctp file, I will make use of this function:

```
$u = $this->requestAction('../hello'); 
if($u==2){
echo "welcome back, my friend";
}
else{
echo "Hello World";
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid the use of `$this->requestAction()` - `hello()` should be called from the view action and the result passed as a view variable.

Reusability is managed on a cascading system - on the controller it may be accessed by any method on the same controller. On app_controller it can be accessed from any controller. The same principle applies if it is data related - it goes on the model or app_model.

By applying the principles of MVC and OO properly, you're already doing things optimally.

Answer (score 1):

It seems for me that you can do the job easier. You do not need that method in your controller. You can access anything stored in the session by using [Session helper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/484/Session):

```
if($session->read('user')){
    echo "welcome back, my friend";
}else{
    echo "Hello World";
}
```